# why we need to use () with and in two select?

Tags: mysql

i try to use and with two select statements like this :

```
mysql> select 1 and select 2;
```

and this give me an error :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'select 2' at line 1

and i solve it by adding () in second select:

```
mysql> select 1 and (select 2);
```

result:

```
+------------------+
| 1 and (select 2) |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

so why adding () solve this ? what does () really do ?

Comment: Why not just `SELECT 1, 2`?

Comment: Your first query is syntactically incorrect - your are only allowed 1 select statement in a query - BUT you can have as many sub queries as required (ie a select in brackets)  Your second query does not make sense but it is syntactically correct (bizarrely)

Comment: @TimLewis more like `select 1 and 2`

Comment: @Shadow Sure; not really sure the point of the query, but either or.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how the [subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html) syntax is defined:

> A subquery must always appear within parentheses.

In any case, if the query runs at all it's because boolean expressions in MySQL actually return `0` or `1`. That's a MySQL peculiarity that other DBMS don't normally have. For example:

- [MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=85a31ff30853bbc0c3712c10210c2b74):

  ```
   SELECT 'foo' = 'bar', 'foo' <> 'bar'
   -- 0 1
  ```
- [Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ca8a85aa7e454da31822134051a8e15d):

  ```
  SELECT 'foo' = 'bar', 'foo' <> 'bar' FROM DUAL
  -- ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
  ```
- [SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=85a31ff30853bbc0c3712c10210c2b74):

  ```
  SELECT 'foo' = 'bar', 'foo' <> 'bar'
  -- Msg 102 Level 15 State 1 Line 1
  -- Incorrect syntax near '<'.
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if perhaps what you were looking to achieve is to return 2 records in your results. Do you need a UNION instead of an AND?

```
SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2;
```

this would give you the result of 2 rows

```
1
2
```